# Adding results to objects

Tags: javascript

I have a small function which adds a returned result to a list of objects but the problem i have is if there is a certain duplicate it will not allow it - but there are some aspects where duplication occurs and other aspects which do not...

I'll explain better with example:

```
var data = {"24":{"16":["172"],"15":["160"]}}
```

This list of data translates to :

```
var data = {"X":{"Y":["id"],"Y":["id"]}};
```

Now im trying to insert new data like this:

```
    for(var key in result){              
      if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)){  
      data[key] = result[key];     
        }
    }
```

If you consider grid co-ordinates,  in my list of objects, Y cannot be duplicated in the same X and X can not be duplicated at all.

This is example data of "result" that im trying to insert:

```
{24: {13:[187]}}
```

Thus turning var data to :

```
var data = {"24":{"16":["172"],"15":["160"],"13":["187"]}};
```

Does any one know how i can implement a duplication check for my loop ?

Comment: Can't you just test `if (key in data)` or `if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))` before trying to add it?

Comment: but if key turns out to be in data how will it add the rest of the data.. for example.. if X is already found it still needs to add Y[id] to the already existing X

Comment: I don't know the cases where you want to duplicate data and when you don't, I thought `in` may help you decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare this temporary object we'll use later
var obj = {}

for ( var key in result ){              
    if ( result.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        // If the key already exists
        if ( data[ key ] === result[ key ] ) {

            // Empty the temporary object
            obj = {}
            // Loop through the subkeys
            for ( var subkey in result[ key ] ) {              
                if ( result[ key ].hasOwnProperty( [ subkey ] ) ) {

                    // Fill in the temporary object
                    obj[ subkey ] = result[ key ][ subkey ]
                }
            }

            // Add the new object to the original object
            data[ key ] = obj
        }

        // If the key doesn't exist, do it normally
        else {
            data[ key ] = result[ key ]
        }
    }
}

// Now, to be tedious, let's free up the memory of the temporary object!
obj = null
```

Something like this should work. If there is a collision, I rebuild the inline object so that I can add it back with all the original and new keys/values.

PS: the last line is just for fun.

Comment: Thanks you just answered a question i was about to ask about freeing memory up :P ! Spooky :P
I will try this script out ! Thanks !